# Is this another identity of exponential formula

Tags: calculus

As written in Wiki, $e^x=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$.

However, does anyone agree that $$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1+0.5\frac{x}{n}}{1-0.5\frac{x}{n}}\right)^n ?$$

Comment: @Travis: Seriously? [left]?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just a typo, I'm not sure how that got into the tag list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can push the limit operation to the numerator and the denominator and evaluate the limits separately. The result will be $\displaystyle\frac{e^{0.5x}}{e^{-0.5x}} = e^x$.

Comment: so it seem i be using mid point method does hold as well.
using
y1+((y1+y2)/2)(x/n)=y2 and continue sequence as y2+((y2+y3)/2)(x/n)=y3, continue the sequence and reach the above formula

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your expression is correct.

Comment: **Hint:** Write $\bigg(1+0.5\dfrac xn\bigg)=\bigg(1-0.5\dfrac xn\bigg)+2\cdot0.5\dfrac xn$

Answer (score 3):

You are right:

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left(  \left( 1+{\frac {ax}{n}} \right) 
 \left( 1+{\frac {bx}{n}} \right) ^{-1} \right) ^{n}={{\rm e}^{x
 \left( a-b \right) }}
$$

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left(  \left( 1+{\frac {ax}{n}} \right) 
 \left( 1+{\frac { \left( a-1 \right) x}{n}} \right) ^{-1} \right) ^{n
}={{\rm e}^{x}}
$$